# Can you use RequestFactory's .with() method with named queries?

Tags: sql, gwt, requestfactory

I'm trying to make a call to a database using RequestFactory with Hibernate/JPA, and I want to retrieve a list of entities with embedded entities returned as well. I know that the .with() method works for methods like .find(), but it doesn't seem to work with custom queries.

The current way I'm doing it is as follows:

I used a named query in the entity class for the query. (Primary Entity is Name, embedded entity is a Suffix entity called nameSuffix)

```
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Query.name", query = "select * from NameTable") })
```

Then in the service class, the .list() method, which is what I'd like to call with RequestFactory, is as follows.

```
public List<Name> list() {
    return emp.get().createNamedQuery("Query.name").getResultList();
}
```

Finally, this is how I make the call in my client side code:

```
NameRequest context = requestFactory.createNameRequest();
context.list().with("nameSuffix").fire(new Receiver<List<NameProxy>>(){
    public void onSuccess(List<NameProxy> response) {
       String suff = response.get(0).getNameSuffix().getText();

    }
});
```

In the above code, it says that getNameSuffix() returns null, which would imply that `.with("nameSuffix")` does not work with the `.list()` call like it does with the standard `.find()` method.

Is there a way to build a call that would return a list of entities and their embedded entities using `.with()`, or do I need to do it another way? If I need to do it another way, has anyone figured out a good way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood what the method `with()` is thought for, unless you had a method `getNameSuffix` which returns the `NameSuffix`entity. This is what the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#relationships) says about it:

`When querying the server, RequestFactory does not automatically populate relations in the object graph. To do this, use the with() method on a request and specify the related property name as a String`

So, what you have to pass to the method is a list of the **name of the child entities** you want to retrieve. I hope this example could be helpful:

```
class A {
   String getS(){return "s-a"}
   B getB(){return new B();}
}
class B {
   String getS(){return "s-b";}
   C getC(){return new C();}
}
class C {
   String getS(){return "s-c";}
}

context.getA().fire(new Receiver<A>(){
  public void onSuccess(A response) {
    // return 's-a'
    response.getS();
    // trhows a NPE
    response.getB().getS(); 
  }
});
context.getA().with("b").fire(new Receiver<A>(){
  public void onSuccess(A response) {
    // return 's-a'
    response.getS();
    // return 's-b'
    response.getB().getS(); 
    // trhows a NPE
    response.getB().getC().getS(); 
  }
});
context.getA().with("b.c").fire(new Receiver<A>(){
  public void onSuccess(A response) {
    // return 's-a'
    response.getS();
    // return 's-b'
    response.getB().getS(); 
    // return 's-c'
    response.getB().getC().getS(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but no, I do understand that I'm sending it the name. I understand .with() relatively well, and can use it just fine with .find() methods. Where I'm hoping for some help is being able to use .with() on calls that use NamedQueries, which may not be possible.

Comment: Gotcha. Why dont you send the named-query as a parameter of the remote method? `rq.list("namedQuery")`

Comment: I'm not sure what that would help with. The named query gets called just fine, but I don't get embedded entities back in the returned entity.